# Unable to create Maven project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Don't know where the problem exactly is.
When trying to create a Java Maven simple project (war, if that means anything) from scratch in Eclipse Helios (also tried Kepler) I get the messages below:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'j2eeexample'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
```

I'm using:

- m2e ver. 1.2.0.20120903-1050 (also tried to use the recent one with Kepler - got the same error)
- apache maven ver. 3.0.4 (also tried 3.1.1 with Kepler) with MAVEN_HOME and PATH set.
- jdk 1.7.0_45
- OS Windows 7 Pro

  ```
  mvn --version
  ```

  returns quite a normal result and, I guess, is configured well.

I did everything the same as mr.Arthur Vin did (including preparations from previous parts of a tutorial) in here: http://youtu.be/1cHIZTmN0z8?t=4m51s

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have **maven-resources-plugin** and maven tried to download it. If you are under a proxy, configure the proxy in your maven **settings.xml** file. If you are not under a proxy, try to download maven again and replace your current installation. May be a local issue with your firewall, well you need to check your internet access.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a proxy. Eclipse is configured to use it and successfully installs software. I added a proxy server to a settings.xml, but that haven't made the trick :( Maybe m2e need some extra configuration too?

Comment: m2e is the eclipse plugin for maven, it will use the eclipse proxy configuration. I'm pretty sure the problem is the proxy. Do the configuration like this [proxy configuration](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html). Open a cmd, go to the project folder, type maven install. If it works there, the problem is in your Eclipse ok?

Comment: It looks like our company uses NTLM proxy. I found a solution how to figure that out in here: http://thiranjith.com/2012/10/31/how-to-configure-maven-to-work-with-ntlm-proxies/ Thanks for advices, Lucas!